# Can I use Catalyst to display images or graphs?

Tags: perl, cgi, catalyst

I have simple Perl/CGI scripts based web server which is mainly used to display graphs and images. I am looking to make it more technical and come to know about Catalyst. I have installed all the required Perl modules on my test platform and created an application called myweb. Also, I am going through the Catalyst documents to reach my goal but nothing helpful yet.

1. Is Catalyst helpful to display
   images/graphs on web?
2. How can I use my existing CGI/Perl
   scritps with Catalyst?

Any example would be really appreciated.

Comment: Catalyst is a web framework. It doesn't care what your content is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Is Catalyst helpful to display images/graphs on web?***

Whatever you currently do in your CGI script will also work in same way within Catalyst (view).

However you can improve/change your method by using an already prescribed [`Catalyst::View`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=catalyst%3A%3Aview%3A%3A*&mode=all) from CPAN.

***How to use my existing cgi/perl scritps with Catalyst?***

You can just embed your CGI script within Catalyst using [`Catalyst::Controller::CGIBin`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Controller-WrapCGI/)

However to get the full benefits of Catalyst [`MVC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) then it would be better to rewrite you CGI script into necessary component parts (Model, View & Controller).

Answer (score 1):

Check out Catalyst::View::Graphics::Primitive for graphics stuff Catalyst.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Catalyst::View::Jemplate

This keeps my controller logic completely independent of what type of graph/chart API I use.
In fact, I change the graph look and feel every few months just because i can..